# kableExtra::text_spec - Rotate Text - Unwanted Commas

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, blogdown

Using RSTudio > Blogdown > Hugo to create a blog
Inserting this R in a post. When the HTML is rendered there are commas between the rotated letters. Why is that?

[image]

```
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
library("dplyr")
library("formattable")
library("stringr")
library("tidyverse")

p1 <- c("R Markdown is pretty neat. You can do things like this. I wonder why more people don't")
p1 <- c("Hello World!")
p2 <- c("do this. It's so much easier to read. NOTE: Those people live here.")

p_text <- unlist(strsplit(p1, "")) # strsplit returns a list. Make it a vector.
num_char <- length(p_text)

p_angle <- seq(30, 360, 30) 
num_ang <- length(p_angle)
p_angle_long <- rep(p_angle, ceiling(num_char / num_ang))  # Repeat the angles for the length of the string
p_angle_long <- p_angle_long[1:num_char]

rtext <- text_spec(p_text, "html", bold = TRUE, angle = p_angle_long)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `text_spec` is a vector with each letter (+ accompanying HTML tags) as a separate element. You can combine into a single string with `paste0`:

````
# Example RMarkdown chunk that produces rotated text:
```{r txt, results='asis'}
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
library("tidyverse")

p1 <- c("Hello World!")
p2 <- c("do this. It's so much easier to read. NOTE: Those people live here.")

p_text <- unlist(strsplit(p1, "")) # strsplit returns a list. Make it a vector.
num_char <- length(p_text)

p_angle <- seq(30, 360, 30) 
num_ang <- length(p_angle)
p_angle_long <- rep(p_angle, ceiling(num_char / num_ang))  
# Repeat the angles for the length of the string
p_angle_long <- p_angle_long[1:num_char]

rtext <- text_spec(p_text, "html", bold = TRUE, angle = p_angle_long)
cat(paste0(rtext, collapse=""))
```
````

Comment: Thank-you for your help!